# Docker errors - Nginx keeps looking for files under /etc/nginx/html

Tags: linux, networking, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I have a [seperate docker container](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/blob/master/docker-compose-separate-containers.yml)  setup with Lesencrypt (using nginx, [nginx-gen](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen), [nginx-letsencrypt](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion))

The Nginx and app containers are working fine but I see errors in Docker logs for Nginx.

I have the volumes for nginx docker at:

```
 - /srv/www/nginx-proxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
 - /srv/www/nginx-proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
 - /srv/www/nginx-proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
 - /srv/www/nginx-proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
```

I see a lot of docker errors in Nginx Docker logs
Most of these errors are caused due to a missing files at `/etc/nginx/html`:

> 2019-03-14T16:41:41.827406845Z 2019/03/14 16:41:41 [error] 10#10: *29
>   "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or
>   directory), client: 162.220.108.178, server: , request: "GET /
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.187.124.124"
>
> 2019-03-14T16:41:44.058864267Z 2019/03/14 16:41:44 [error] 10#10: *30
>   "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or
>   directory), client: 83.224.172.148, server: , request: "GET /
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.43.94.103:80"
>
> 2019-03-14T16:42:49.085729650Z 2019/03/14 16:42:49 [error] 10#10: *37
>   "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or
>   directory), client: 164.52.24.163, server: , request: "GET /
>   HTTP/1.1", host:"xx.187.124.124"
>
> 2019-03-14T16:47:50.012585507Z 2019/03/14 16:47:50 [error] 10#10: *58
>   open()
>   "/etc/nginx/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/7mwlZRBfqpmjH1XKH-Qg7B6lyduFU9EPg4QSaTFyT0s"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 66.133.109.36, server:
>   , request: "GET
>   /.well-known/acme-challenge/7mwlZRBfqpmjH1XKH-Qg7B6lyduFU9EPg4QSaTFyT0s
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "foo.bar"

These are the same with other Docker applications that are deployed.

Say we have a [Wordpress Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) deployed with volumes

```
- ./wordpress:/var/www/html
```

Or say we have a server block setup for external load balancer such as ALB/CloudFront/CloudFlare, this is important for us to mitigate docker errors for these external load balancers to failover to other servers in the event of a server failure.

I see errors for missing files at `/etc/nginx/html/` like the below:

> 2019-03-14T05:38:06.284529777Z 2019/03/14 05:38:06 [error] 11#11: *689
>   "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or
>   directory), client: 78.162.82.29, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1",
>   host:"alb-aws-com" 2019-03-14T06:57:03.020160983Z 2019/03/14 06:57:03
>   [error] 11#11: *1011 open() "/etc/nginx/html/wp-config.php" failed (2:
>   No such file or directory), client: 190.188.94.38, server: , request:
>   "GET /wp-config.php HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx.187.124.124"
>   2019-03-14T06:57:03.020160983Z 2019/03/14 06:57:03 [error] 11#11:
>   *1011 open() "/etc/nginx/html/wp-config.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 190.188.94.38, server: , request: "GET
>   /wp-config.php HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.187.124.124"
>   2019-03-14T06:57:13.402392385Z 2019/03/14 06:57:13 [error] 11#11:
>   *1011 open() "/etc/nginx/html/wp-admins.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 190.188.94.38, server: , request: "POST
>   /wp-admins.php HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.187.124.124"
>   2019-03-14T06:57:13.402392385Z 2019/03/14 06:57:13 [error] 11#11:
>   *1011 open() "/etc/nginx/html/wp-admins.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 190.188.94.38, server: , request: "POST
>   /wp-admins.php HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.187.124.124"
>   2019-03-14T06:58:20.069384814Z 2019/03/14 06:58:20 [error] 11#11:
>   *1018 open() "/etc/nginx/html/wp-content/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/wp-pma-mod/index.php"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 190.188.94.38, server:
>   , request: "GET
>   /wp-content/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/wp-pma-mod/index.php
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.187.124.124" 2019-03-14T06:58:20.069384814Z
>   2019/03/14 06:58:20 [error] 11#11: *1018 open()
>   "/etc/nginx/html/wp-content/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/wp-pma-mod/index.php"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 190.188.94.38, server:
>   , request: "GET
>   /wp-content/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/wp-pma-mod/index.php
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.187.124.124" 2019-03-14T06:58:20.069384814Z
>   2019/03/14 06:58:20 [error] 11#11: *1018 open()
>   "/etc/nginx/html/wp-content/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/wp-pma-mod/index.php"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 190.188.94.38, server:
>   , request: "GET
>   /wp-content/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/wp-pma-mod/index.php
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.187.124.124"

Below are the Nginx and sample webapp(foo.bar) server blocks that are created automatically by the Dockers:

```
server {
        server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
        listen 80;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 503;
}
server {
        server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 503;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/default.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/default.key;
}

server {
        server_name foo.bar;
        listen 80 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        include /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://foo.bar;
        }
}
server {
        server_name foo.bar;
        listen 443 ssl http2 ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
        return 500;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/default.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/default.key;
}
```

Am I missing something or should we consider these errors normal?

Is there a way to get rid of these errors?

Comment: Please show the relevant `server` block.

Comment: Hi Michael, the server blocks are added to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Did you skip one? A default server, maybe?

Comment: I know this is old... but I'm having the same exact issue today.  Was this ever solved @HarishChennamsetty?